# How to Implement Django Loggers/Logging in the code?

Tags: django, logging, django-rest-framework, django-views

As i am a newbie. I'm working on Django Rest Framework using ModelViewset. Can anyone help me out in explaining or understanding, how to implement the loggers/logging? Even i'm using the Django OAuth2 toolkit for authentication, so how can log a username & password?

Comment: You can read about logging on official [doc.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/logging/) there is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41556737/how-to-make-action-logging-in-django-with-django-rest-framework) which will give you an idea about logging in rest

Comment: Thanks @AnkitTiwari. I have gone through those docs but still confused in implementing those settings & codes. I'm using the ModelSerializer

Comment: Hello @AakashBhaikatti did you checked second post it explains how to integrate logger in drf

Comment: Thanks @AnkitTiwari. I'll go through it. If anything needed please do help

Comment: ```raise ValueError('Unable to configure handler '
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file'
``` it is showing error

Comment: I'll suggest you to use official doc. for [logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/logging/#logging)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240589/discussion-between-ankit-tiwari-and-aakash-bhaikatti).

Answer (score 0):

You Don't Need to use Allauth and OAuth2.You can use Django by default authentication functionality.
In this, you just need to create templates .

```
urls.py

    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include # new
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')), # new
    ]
```

Please refer to this Url for more details.
[more details use this link](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-login-and-logout-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks @Akash Nagtilak. But there's a requirement for using OAuth2 authentication. I need to add loggers to the login